# How do i write a placeholder in Django ModelForms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Is it possible to convert the help text in Django Models to placeholders in ModelForms?

models.py

```
class DietaryHabits(Patient):

    DIET_CHOICES = (('V', 'Veg'), ('N', 'NonVeg'),)
    diet_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DIET_CHOICES, default=False)
    breakfast = models.TextField(help_text='Describe your daily Breakfast')
    lunch = models.TextField(help_text='Describe your daily Lunch')
    dinner = models.TextField(help_text='Describe your daily Dinner')
    others = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Describe your other eating habits')
    fasting = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
```

forms.py-

```
class DietaryHabitsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DietaryHabits
        fields = ['diet_type', 'breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'others']
        widgets = {
            'diet_type': forms.RadioSelect,
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Widget Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/). In your case it will look like,

```
class DietaryHabitsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    breakfast = forms.CharField(label='breakfast', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your daily Breakfast'}))
    lunch = forms.CharField(label='lunch', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your daily Lunch'}))
    dinner = forms.CharField(label='dinner', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your daily Dinner'}))
    others = forms.CharField(label='others', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your other eating habits'}))

    class Meta:
        model = DietaryHabits
        fields = ['diet_type', 'breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'others']
        widgets = {
            'diet_type': forms.RadioSelect,
        }
```

or you can fill widgets in `Meta` too,

```
class DietaryHabitsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DietaryHabits
        fields = ['diet_type', 'breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'others']
        widgets = {
            'diet_type': forms.RadioSelect,
            'breakfast': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your daily Breakfast'}),
            'lunch': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your daily Lunch'}),
            'dinner': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your daily Dinner'}),
            'others': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your other eating habits'}),
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way i could write it inside the class Meta? In the above case i would have to write for all fields and it makes no sense in using Model forms then

Comment: Thanks @ Hisham___Pak